# Why am I getting SQLSyntaxErrorException - encountered ""?

Tags: java, jdbc

This method keeps throwing the exception in the title, and I cannot find a reason, I have created other tables through the connection and all the referenced tables have been created. I'm using embedded [JavaDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby).

```
private void createEvidenceTable() throws SQLException
{
    Statement evidenceTable = CONNECTION.createStatement();
    evidenceTable.execute("CREATE TABLE evidence("+
                            "evidence_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"+
                            "date_added VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,"+
                            "evidence_dated VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,"+
                            "evidence_file varchar(20),"+
                            "evidence_text VARCHAR(10),"+
                            "source_location_id INTEGER,"+
                            "source_person_id INTEGER,"+
                            "evidence_type VARCHAR(20),"+
"CONSTRAINT evidence__location_source FOREIGN KEY(source_location_id) REFERENCES location_source,"+
"CONSTRAINT evidence_person_source FOREIGN KEY(source_person_id) REFERENCES person_source,"+
"CONSTARINT evidence_evidence_type FOREIGN KEY(evidence_type) REFERENCES evidence_types)");

}
```

Comment: What database are you trying to create the table in?

Comment: JavaDB, embedded, sorry just did an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One definite problem is that the third constraint clause is misspelled (`CONSTARINT` iso `CONSTRAINT`)

Answer (score 0):

This worked in MySQL client:

```
CREATE TABLE evidence
(
    evidence_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date_added VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    evidence_dated VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    evidence_file varchar(20),
    evidence_text VARCHAR(10),
    source_location_id INTEGER,
    source_person_id INTEGER,
    evidence_type VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(evidence_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(source_location_id) REFERENCES location_source(source_location_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(source_person_id) REFERENCES person_source(source_person_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(evidence_type) REFERENCES evidence_types(evidence_type)
);
```

Why would you use VARCHAR(6) instead of DATE?  Makes little sense to me.